# real analysis: prove the limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

is my attempt correct? any help is appreciated.

Prove that the limit does not exist:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(x+sgn(x))$$

I can prove that by letting

two sequences $x_n$: $1/n \to 0$ and $y_n$: $-1/n \to 0$, $x_n \neq 0$, $y_n \neq 0$, for all $n \in N$

$f(x_n) = (1/n+sgn(1/n)) = (1/n +1) \to 1$

$f(y_n)= (-1/n+sgn(-1/n)) = (-1/n +(-1)) \to -1$

since $f(x_n) \neq f(y_n)$, the limit D.N.E

thank you

Comment: Please use latex formatting! "\lim" instead of "lim", latex missing in the last lines ...

Comment: Yes, what you have done is correct.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is another proof, albeit less rigorous.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}(x+\operatorname{sgn}(x))=\lim\limits_{x\to0}(x)+\lim\limits_{x\to0}(\operatorname{sgn}(x))=0+\lim\limits_{x\to0}(\operatorname{sgn}(x))=\lim\limits_{x\to0}(\operatorname{sgn}(x))$$
In order for the ordinary limit to exist, both the left-side and the right-side limits as $x\to0$ must be equal. Now, $x\to0^-$ means $x\lt0$ and $x\to0^+$ means $x\gt0$. These are two of the three subdomains of the signum function.
$$
\operatorname{sgn}(x)\overset{\text{def}}{=}
\begin{cases}
-1,&\text{if $x\lt0$}\\
0,&\text{if $x=0$}\\
1,&\text{if $x\gt0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, the left-side and right-side limits will not be equal.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}(\operatorname{sgn}(x))=-1\ne1=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}(\operatorname{sgn}(x))$$
As such, the original limit in this problem does not exist.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I think you can only split the limit like you have if both the functions are continuous?

Comment: @sai-kartik We can separate the original ordinary limit into its two one-side limits. As such, it is permissible to separate $x$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ as the limits for those terms exist for both one-side limits. Additionally, the original function is continuous everywhere but $x=0$, but the value of $x$ only approaches $0$; it will not equal it. This is not a misuse of the limit law.

Comment: Oh Okay.. I think I'll have to go look up my definitions again. Thanks for pointing it out :)